# Extract text before first comma with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract text before first comma (first and last name) from strings like:

```
John Smith, RN, BSN, MS
Thom Nev, MD
Foo Bar, MD,RN
```

I tried with regex:

```
(.*)\s(.*),\s
```

but this doesn't work for all situations.
How to achieve this?

Comment: What would you want from a string like `', BMath, MD'`?

Comment: @muistooshort, I don't have such case.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Match everything from the beginning of the string until the first comma:

```
^(.+?),
```

Comment: I understand that ^ means at beginning, .+ means one or zero of any character, but don't know what is purpose of ?.

Comment: @ИванБишевац, `?` in this context means [non-greedy](https://www.google.com/search?q=non+greedy+regular+expression). Basically it means that the expression should match everything until it encounters the *first* `,`. Without `?`, it would look for everything until the *last* `,`. Also, `.+` means "one or more of any character", not "one or zero". "One or zero" is `?` following an atom (for example `ab?c` would match `abc` or `ac`).

Comment: This includes comma itself (at least when I tried that in Sublime). The following option worked for me: ^([^,])+

Answer (score 38):

How about: `yourString.split(",")[0]`

Comment: I accepted answer with regex since I asked for it and want to learn regex. Anyway great answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Note: Found this answer Googling for syntax, and had it start throwing the error "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" - turns out there's some unicode character hiding in there, for anyone else who tries to copy/paste (spli\U+FFC2\U+FFADt(",")[0]).

Comment: It also can be yourString.split(',').first

Answer (score 26):

```
^([^,])+
```

This regexp worked for me in Sublime. It selected everything just before the first comma.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The OP asked for everything before the comma and the accepted answer includes the comma.

Answer (score 13):

How about the following:

```
[^,]*
```

`[^,]*` means "match any number of characters that are not commas", which I think it exactly what you are trying to do here.  You may want to anchor it to the beginning of the string iwth `^`, like this:

```
^[^,]*
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use non greedy regex operators, try: `(.+?),` instead of: `(.+),`. Note that when using greedy operators, you'll match everything before the last comma instead of the first.

Answer (score -4):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

..use this ... this is the correct answer to get first comma separated value

Comment: One simple special letter and it's broken.