findFirstIn function not work the comma (,) in scala to extract substring from string (this substring not always come at first of the string)
I have string i want to substring it i try use findFirstIn but it did not work with comma
what i want :
i have this string : "[{eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,app:5}]" i just want to get from it  eventTax:0
what i try : I try 3 regex but all of them not working
"eventTax:.*[\\,]".r.findFirstIn("[{eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,app:5}]")
val res34: Option[String] = Some(eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,)

"eventTax:.*[,]".r.findFirstIn("[{eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,app:5}]")
val res35: Option[String] = Some(eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,)

"eventTax:.*,".r.findFirstIn("[{eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,app:5}]")
val res36: Option[String] = Some(eventTax:0,eventExtraAdditionalDetails:8,)

is there are any way to write the regex to get only eventTax:0 ?

eventTax:\\d+. But if there can be anything but a comma, just replace .*, (or .*[,] or .*[\\,]) with [^,]*

this will work if the value after eventTax is number , i need general solution so even if the value after eventTax is string then to take it and stop only when first , come

why was question closed and linked to Ruby answer? You may use reluctant quantifier and postitive lookahead for comma: "eventTax:.*?(?=,)".r

thanks @WiktorStribiżew using [^,]* sort the issue

@DmitriiNikiforov Where is a Ruby here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12148811/3832970

@Code. Do not use .*?(?=,), it is unnecessarily "complex" compared to [^,]*, a mere negated character class, supported by every regex flavor.
